# Custom class with prefix not showing up in custom class combo box in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, class, interface-builder

If I create a custom class called MTViewController that is derived from UIViewController, I can't select it in the custom class combo box in Interface Builder in XCode 4.5. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's a bug of Interface builder. And also it's not related with UIViewController or MTViewController. For some reason it doesn't show some of the newly added  class names over there but if you type it yourself and run the application you don't get any errors.

Moreover you can try this, after creating a class just close the project and open it again . If you go to identitiy inspector this time you will see the class name there. SO in my opinion it is a bug in XCode.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah I think it's a bug too. I reopened the project and it appeared in the list

Comment: I can also confirm this bug. As soon as I move away from the Identity Inspector it gets reset. Xcode 4.5 is causing me some other trouble as well.. stupid Apple won't release a public bug tracker to show us how soon this might be fixed.

Comment: I found that removing the missing view controller class files from the project and then re-adding them resolved the issue in IB for me.

(Typing the class name manually and closing/reopening the project didn't work, though.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try  any of these steps.

1. Make sure it inherits UIViewController. @interface MTViewController : UIViewController
2. Under target check in build phase if MTViewController.m is present
3. Delete the UIViewController UI object and put it back again and check if its appears back in custom class
4. Just to reset it close your project and open it back again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just upgraded my iMac and Macbook to Xcode 6.3. On my iMac everything was rosey with my project but on my Macbook I could not get any of my custom view controllers to appear in the custom class field of the file owner of any of my xibs. Even creating a new project still wouldn't work. I knew it wasn't a problem with my project because it worked on my iMac.

So after hours of trying different solutions and tweaks the only thing that worked was uninstalling Xcode 6.3 and re-installing it. I believe this problem came out of the something getting out of sync as I have upgraded through multiple versions of Xcode over the years.

Save yourself the headaches for anyone reading this and start with a clean version of Xcode if you get this problem.